# SafetyNet attestation API deprecated

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

This is a message from google play. I am not directly using the safety net attestation. The migration document is not much help to me. The only part of my app that might be involved with safetyNet is com.google.android.gms. So where should I make the changes. If anyone could please shed some light on why I am getting this issue and how I can fix it.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: has anyone figured out a solution for Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your firebase BOM library with below version

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')

Comment: where exactly do I put that ins my Flutter app?

Comment: @Chris in app level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked this yet but following is the steps they have mentioned for proper migration:-

- If you’ve defined your anti-abuse strategy and are using the
  SafetyNet Attestation API, you’ll need to [set up](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup) the Play
  Integrity API from your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers), then follow the [migration
  guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/migrate).
- If you’re not distributing your app through Google Play, you can use
  the Play Integrity API from the Google Cloud Console by following
  these [steps](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#apps-exclusively-distributed-outside-google-play). By using this process, you don't have to create a
  Play developer account or publish a release in the Google Play
  Console.

Comment: If I am not wrong, Play Integrity API works only for apps distributed through Play Store